# $f(x) = x^2 - \sin2x$ function, slope and degrees

Tags: functions, trigonometry

I'm new here and sorry for my bad English, not my first language.
Anyway, I have this function:

$f(x) = x^2 - \sin2x\;,\;\;\left[-\frac\pi2< x <0\right]$

And I've been asked to find what is:

1. Find what are the values $(x,y)$ for the points which the function have the max slope and the min slope.
2. For each point that was found in the first task - How much degrees the tangent of the function creates with the positive direction of $x$ axis (of the graph).

I'm stuck at the second task. For the first task what I did is just to derive the function, then simple to find the min or max points, and so on.
However, I don't know how to find the degrees and I don't know if I need to use the fact I know the slope is $\tan x$.

Thanks for helping me,
Sonis

Answer (score 1):

You are requested to find the maximum and minimum of the derivative, which can be done in the standard way:
$$
f'(x)=2x-2\cos2x
$$
The derivative is
$$
f''(x)=2+4\sin2x
$$
that vanishes when
$$
\sin2x=-1/2
$$
so when
$$
2x=-\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
2x=\pi+\frac{\pi}{6}+2k\pi
$$
that means
$$
x=-\frac{\pi}{12}+k\pi
\qquad\text{or}\qquad
x=\frac{7\pi}{12}+k\pi
$$
the solutions in the interval $(-\pi/2,0)$ are $-\pi/12\approx-0.26$ and $-5\pi/12\approx-1.31$.

Since
$$
f'''(x)=8\cos2x
$$
and
$$
f'''(-\pi/12)>0,\qquad f'''(-5\pi/12)<0
$$
we know the former is a point of minimum and the latter a point of maximum.

So the minimum slope is
$$
f'(-\pi/12)=-\frac{\pi}{6}-\sqrt{3}
$$
and the maximum slope is
$$
f'(-5\pi/12)=-\frac{5\pi}{6}+\sqrt{3}
$$
The slope is the trigonometric tangent of the angle the tangent line forms with the $x$-axis, so we have to compute
$$
\arctan\left(-\frac{\pi}{6}-\sqrt{3}\right)\approx-66.09^\circ
$$
and
$$
\arctan\left(-\frac{5\pi}{6}+\sqrt{3}\right)\approx-41.54^\circ
$$

Comment: Thanks, that what I did but the part of "arctan" is not clear. Why do you use arctan in the end?

Comment: @Sonis In order to pass from the slope to the angle

Comment: but $m=tanx$ not $arctanx$, so please explain it again... still don't understand why arctan

Comment: @Sonis The minimum and maximum values we found are $\tan a$ and $\tan b$, where $a$ and $b$ are the angles you have to mention. So, if $m_\min$ and $m_\max$ are the minimum and maximum slopes, the angles are $\arctan m_\min$ and $\arctan m_\max$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Try sketching the line out. Draw a line on an xy-plane and then from one point on the line above the x-axis, drop an altitude down to the x-axis. From this, you should have a right triangle from the original point, down to the x-axis, to the x-intercept. Now, find the tangent of the angle at the x-intercept. Compare this tangent with the slope. Are they the same?

**Hint 2:**

You can also do it algebraically using the y-intercept and x-intercept. There is a a right triangle involving the y-intercept, origin, and x-intercept with the right angle at the origin, so you can find the tangent of the angle at the x-intercept with this formula:
$$\frac{\text{Distance between y-intercept and origin}}{\text{Distance between x-intercept and origin}}$$

This ratio has to be positive because distances are always positive. However, this is the tangent of the acute angle at the x-intercept. If the acute angle is with the negative x-axis, then you need to take the negative of the tangent to find the obtuse angle at the x-intercept. For what slopes does that happen?

Comment: First of all, thank you for trying to help.
I'm not sure I understand what you reccomend me to to do.
Moreover, how can I solve this by calculting and not only by sketch?
Thanks again

Comment: Well, you can also do it algebraically using the y-intercept and x-intercept. There is a a right triangle involving the y-intercept, origin, and x-intercept with the right angle at the origin, so you can find the tangent of the angle at the x-intercept with this formula:
$$\frac{\text{Distance between y-intercept and origin}}{\text{Distance between x-intercept and origin}}$$

Comment: However, this is the tangent of the acute angle at the x-intercept. If the acute angle is with the negative x-axis, then you need to take the negative of the tangent to find the obtuse angle at the x-intercept. For what slopes does that happen? It's kind of hard to do this without sketching it out, but is certainly doable. I just think sketching the line is easier.

Comment: My english is not so goos so I have so troubles understanding what to do, sorry but thanks